# Laravel Join with where not in gives "Column xxxxx in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous"

Tags: laravel, join

I have two tables: `leads` and `hts_patients`. Both table has `phone` column and I want to list all leads that has no record on `hts_patients` table(foreign key is `phone`).

So far, I have tried this and it works but taking so much long time.

```
 $countries = ['DE','TR'];
    $dateS = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth(4);
    $dateE = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
    $leads = Lead::whereBetween('created_at',[$dateS,$dateE])->whereIn('visitor_country',$countries)
        ->select('id','name','phone','visitor_country','source','description','contact','created_at')->get();
    $patient = HtsPatient::pluck('phone');
    foreach ($leads as $key=>$item){
        if (isset($item->phone)){
            $data =$patient->where('phone',$item->phone)->first();
            if (!empty($data)){
                $leads->forget($key);
            }
        }
    }
    return view('poll.leadSecond',['leads' => $leads]);
```

Thing, that I want is probably something like this;

```
 $countries = ['DE','TR'];
    $dateS = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth(4);
    $dateE = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth();
    $leads = DB::table('leads')->join('hts_patients','hts_patients.phone', '=', 'leads.phone')
    ->whereBetween('leads.created_at',[$dateS,$dateE])->whereIn('leads.visitor_country',$countries)
        ->whereNotIn('phone', function($query) {
            $query->select('phone')
                ->from('hts_patients');
        })
        ->select('leads.id','leads.name','leads.phone','leads.visitor_country','leads.source','leads.description','leads.contact','leads.created_at')->get();
```

But it gives an error says

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'phone'
> in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

you have tow tables with column called 'phone', in your whereNotIn clause you should specify witch on you wants.

I think the result should be like:

```
 ->whereNotIn('leads.phone', function($query) {
            $query->select('hts_patients.phone');
             //   ->from('hts_patients'); you do not need this 'from'
        })
```

Comment: sorry my fault. I've changed code exactly as you said but it returns empty collection but there is a lot records for sure